# How's using FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions different from using stat -f %A?

Tags: cocoa, swift4, nsfilemanager, stat

I'm trying to get the posix permissions of a file, but when I use the key `FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions` (originally `NSFilePosixPermissions`) to retrieve the numerical posix permissions value, it returned `511 (-r-x--x--x)`, but when I use `stat -f %A /path/to/file` in Terminal, it returned `777 (-rwxrwxrwx)` which is the correct one (I used `chmod 777 /path/to/file`, so it should be `777 (-rwxrwxrwx)`).

This is my code using `FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions` (Swift 4):

```
var numericalValue = "000"
if let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: "/path/to/file") {
    if let posixPermissions = attributes[.posixPermissions] as? NSNumber {
        numericalValue = posixPermissions.stringValue
    }
}
```

I don't know what is going on, I'm wondering how is the value returned from `FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions` different from the output of `stat -f %A /path/to/file` or `stat -x /path/to/file`, can anyone please help me to figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display the result in octal:

```
if let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: "/path/to/file") {
    if let posixPermissions = attributes[.posixPermissions] as? NSNumber {
        let octal = String(posixPermissions.intValue, radix: 8, uppercase: false)
        print(octal)
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a fun question! Luckily, Swift has a real useful String init function for it.

Comment: Yeah, it worked but still I don’t get it, what does this init function do?

Comment: NSNumber is just that, a numeric value without implicit instructions on how to show it. But you can show a number to a human in a number of ways. You could display it in Roman numerals, for example. But the usual way is to show it decimally, i.e. using 0 to 9. That's called "base 10". This init function could be used for that, with the radix parameter set to 10. But that's silly, you'd simply use (String describing:). But for octal representation (using numbers 0-7) you set radix to 8. And for hexadecimal (using numbers 0-9 and A-F), you'd set radix to 16.